Manage Cookies on localhost
I know, Cookies are not shared on different ports on localhost, but:

I created a local alias dev.myDomain.com in the hosts file: 127.0.0.1   dev.myDomain.com
I have two local web apps, dev.myDomain.com:60030 which manage them and dev.myDomain.com:50030 which uses them
I am able to set a Cookie in the 60030 and I can see it in the 50030, it works.

This is how I set one:
func (c *AuthController) setCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, value string, expires time.Time) {

    // Set the cookie by setting it with a past expiration date
    // if value is empty string, cookie is removed from client
    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "my_cookie",
        Value:    value,                   // Cookie value
        Path:     "/",                     // Path where the cookie is valid. 
        Domain:   "dev.myDomain.com",          // Ensure domain matches where the cookie was set.
        Expires:  expires,                 // Set the expiration
        HttpOnly: true,                    // not visible in javascript
        Secure:   true,                    // Set to true for HTTPS connections
        SameSite: http.SameSiteLaxMode,
    })
}

I set it calling:
expires := 7 * 24 * time.Hour // 1 week
c.setCookie(w, session.ID.String(), time.Now().Add(expires)) 

I remove it calling:
c.setCookie(w, "", time.Unix(0, 0))

If I call the web app 60030/api/v1/logout from browser it works. If I call it from the web app 50030 by Ajax call, the call works, the code runs through, I get 200, but the Cookie is not removed.
Any idea?

If you look at the Application tab of your browser's dev-tools, you will see that under the cookies storage panel, there is a cookie with the domain name myDomain.com but with the port 60030 following the domain name (like this myDomain.com:60030). This results in non-accessible cookies. Cookies are only accessible within the same port they are generated. I recommend you to create subdomains instead of using port as a difference.
127.0.0.1 server.myDomain.local
127.0.0.1 client.myDomain.local

Now you can run both server App and client App under the same port in order to share the same cookie. Then you must use domain => *.myDomain.local when you set the cookie.

Well, I am using a subdomain, I updated the question. The point is that setting the Cookie actually does work. I have problems just deleting it.

To delete a cookie use this
http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{ Name:     "my_cookie", Value:    "", Path:     "/", Domain:   "dev.myDomain.com",  Expires:  0 })

Tried, doesn't delete it.

Your domaine should be *.myDomain.com for both the creation and the deletion config. Not dev.myDomain.com. If you use dev.myDomain you must delete the cookie from the dev app. A cookie can only be modified by apps that belong to the same domain appearing inside the cookie

Yes, that's clear, but correct me if I am wrong. As long as I want to run two applications on localhost, they can't have the same port, and on having different ports the cookies are not shared. right?

You can run many applications on the same port with different subdomains. You should install a webServer (nginx or apache) and configure virtualhosts for each app

Ok, but i fear it's too much work just for a local test.

May be you should use another approche to explain what you want to do. For me, as I see, you are attempting to create a frontend app that exchange datas with the backend. So you should look at the API driven developpement with tokens exchange in order to handle authentications, not a cookie driven approche.

I am creating a simple SSO system, each sso system works with at least one cookie and I am trying to build a local test environment.

SSO is juste a way to exchange a valid token from Auth-Central app to others apps. Most of times, it is a JWT token. The client app has a protected ressourse that needs a JWT for access. If the JWT is invalid, the app will redirect user to the SSO login page. After user is successfully logged in, the redirect-URL of that app is called in order to handle an authorization code. Now the app has acces to you account, it can retrieve personal information in order to generate a JWT  encrypted by the app-key and respond the user terminal with the generated JWT. Only SSO's backend need a cookie.
